# Datagridview in vb.net issues

Tags: datagridview

I'm using a datagridview and would like to give the end-user the capability to edit the "Notes" cell which is the 5th column.  The datagridview is named "dgvScheduleInfo".
If I put the following code in, it works fine but opens up ALL cells to edit which I don't want:

```
dgvScheduleInfo.ReadOnly = False
```

If, for testing purposes, I use

```
dgvScheduleInfo.Rows(3).Cells(5).ReadOnly = False
```

(hard code  a row/cell) this does not work.

And inevitably

```
dgvScheduleInfo.Rows(dgvScheduleInfo.CurrentRow.Index).Cells(5).ReadOnly = False
```

does not work either.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Make the columns or rows ReadOnly instead individual cells.
Use following code after DataGridview is filled/Bound. You may also make it readonly through datasource(if its a datatable)

```
For Each col As DataGridViewColumn In dgvScheduleInfo.Columns
 If col.Index = 5 Then
   col.ReadOnly = False
   Else
   col.ReadOnly = True
 End If
Next
```